# undefind method firstname= while using factory_girl and rspec tests

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot, rspec-rails, nomethoderror

http://everydayrails.com/2012/03/19/testing-series-rspec-models-factory-girl.html#
going off of this tutorial currently. i am adding on to another project that i started from the rails apps tutorial.

as i go to create my models specs 
    contact_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Contact do 
it "has a valid factory" do
    FactoryGirl.create(:contact).should be_valid
end
it "is invalid without a firstname"
it "is invalid without a lastname"
it "returns a contact's full name as a string"  
end
```

factories/contacts.rb

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :contact do |f|
    f.firstname { Faker::Name.first_name }
    f.lastname { Faker::Name.last_name }
    end
end
```

i run rspec and recieve this error:

```
    1) Contact has a valid factory
    Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:contact).should be_valid
    NoMethodError:
    undefined method `firstname=' for #<Contact name: nil, email: nil, content: nil>
    # ./spec/models/contact_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    Finished in 0.22028 seconds
    4 examples, 1 failure, 3 pending
```

here is my contact model

```
 class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_no_table

  column :name, :string
  column :email, :string
  column :content, :string

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_presence_of :content
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}\z/i
  validates_length_of :content, :maximum => 500

  def update_spreadsheet
    connection = GoogleDrive.login(ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"], ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"])
    ss = connection.spreadsheet_by_title('Learn-Rails-Example')
     if ss.nil?
      ss = connection.create_spreadsheet('Learn-Rails-Example')
    end
    ws = ss.worksheets[0]
    last_row = 1 + ws.num_rows
    ws[last_row, 1] = Time.new
    ws[last_row, 2] = self.name
    ws[last_row, 3] = self.email
    ws[last_row, 4] = self.content
    ws.save
  end

end
```

and my contactS_controller

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(secure_params[:contact])
    if @contact.valid?
      @contact.update_spreadsheet
      UserMailer.contact_email(@contact).deliver
      flash[:notice] = "Message sent from #{@contact.name}."
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def secure_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :content)
  end

end
```

i tried changing :name to be :firstname, and :lastname and ended up getting this new error

```
1) Contact has a valid factory
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:contact).should be_valid
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email can't be blank, Email is invalid, Content can't be blank
     # ./spec/models/contact_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.22596 seconds
4 examples, 1 failure, 3 pending

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/contact_spec.rb:4 # Contact has a valid factory
```

my guess is that i havent defined something right when i reference to :contact.

**edit**
adding the Faker::Internet.email attr brought up a new error

```
 1) Contact has a valid factory
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:contact).should be_valid
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Content can't be blank
     # ./spec/models/contact_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

so i comment out validates_presence_of :content, column :content, and validates_length_of :content and get this

```
 1) Contact has a valid factory
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:contact).should be_valid
     ActiveRecord::Tableless::NoDatabase:
       Can't #create_record a Tableless object
     # ./spec/models/contact_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

so it seems that things are working as i apply them or take away, i apparently have lots of conflicts between the code i wrote following one tutorial and adding this method using rspec factory_girl and faker

**edit 2**
so after the addition of the email and content attr, i continued on with filling out the remaining specs  for "invalid without first/lastname":

```
    describe Contact do 
            it "has a valid factory" do
        FactoryGirl.build(:contact).should be_valid
        end
        it "is invalid without a firstname" do 
            FactoryGirl.build(:contact, lastname: nil).should_not be_valid 
        end

         it "is invalid without a lastname" do 
            FactoryGirl.build(:contact, lastname: nil).should_not be_valid 
        end

        it "returns a contact's full name as a string"  
    end
```

and my tests passed with no errors:

```
  is invalid without a lastname
  has a valid factory
  is invalid without a firstname
  returns a contact's full name as a string (PENDING: Not yet implemented)

Pending:
  Contact returns a contact's full name as a string
    # Not yet implemented
    # ./spec/models/contact_spec.rb:15

Finished in 0.22146 seconds
4 examples, 0 failures, 1 pending
```

thank you sonnyhe2002 for getting me through this! much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an email attr to your factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :contact do |f|
    f.firstname { Faker::Name.first_name }
    f.lastname { Faker::Name.last_name }
    f.email { Faker::Internet.email }
    f.content 'This is content'
  end
end
```

Since you are using has_no_table, I think factory cannot save it into the database.

You should use 'build' instead of 'create'

```
FactoryGirl.build(:contact).should be_valid
```

Comment: Adding the `email` is not enough.

Comment: adding the email attr helped, im now trying to find the attr for content. could i possibly remove the :content from my secure_parameters in the controller?

Comment: So One step is to add the f.content, the next error i still have to figure out

Comment: I think you also need to ues build instead, check the edited answer

Comment: adding the two lines for the factory and changing from create to build yields no change in result, still showing the cant create tabless object message. from that i am assuming that what you have suggested is of benefit. would this help to pass the remaining error https://github.com/softace/activerecord-tableless?

Comment: nevermind i didnt realize i had already put that gem into my gemfile

Comment: What if you do not use factorygirl to create the method, what does the rspec say if you use   Contact.new(first_name: 'a', last_name: 'b', email: 'c@d.com', content: 'f').should be_valid

Comment: i did not try your latest method, but what i did do is complete contact_spec with:  it "is invalid without a firstname" do 
   FactoryGirl.build(:contact, lastname: nil).should_not be_valid 
  end

   it "is invalid without a lastname" do 
   FactoryGirl.build(:contact, lastname: nil).should_not be_valid 
  end  . everything is passing now with one pending for "returns contacts full name". is there any explaination as to why it passes now opposed to before the rest of the code was added?

Comment: It passes because all the validates in your Contact model is there. I would take those out and run the test, so see it fail, in case of false positives.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have a `firstname` column in your database? Make sure `db/schema.rb` has a `firstname` column for the `contacts` table, and make sure you've run `rake db:test:prepare`

Comment: (ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 0) do

    end)    this is all that is in db/schema.rb after rake db:test:prepare

Answer (score 0):

The errors given are quite self-descriptive: you have some validators on your `email` and `content` attributes but you are not setting these attributes in your `Contact` Factory to make valid your model.

Edit: please add this to your contact factory:

```
f.email 'email@example.com'
f.content 'a content'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model:

```
validates_presence_of :name
validates_presence_of :email
validates_presence_of :content
validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}\z/i
validates_length_of :content, :maximum => 500
```

so, while making a `FactoryGirl` user you need to consider the above facts. You only handled the presence of **email** and **name**, but also need to handle the presence of **content** which needs to be less than 500 characters in length.

Answer (score 0):

FactoryGirl is now replaced by FactoryBot. FactoryGirl is deprecated.

FactoryBot version 5 onwards only supports dynamic attributes while creating the factory.

So the solution is:-

`FactoryBot.define do
     factory :user do
         name                 { "Ron" }
         email                { "ron@gmail.com" }
         password             { "ronY123" }
         password_confirmation { "ronY123" }
     end
 end`

Comment: Assigning static attributes is deprecated.